# Use custom testing model in Laravel 7 tests

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit, laravel-7

I'm writing a basic repository with basic methods, to have it extended from other repositories, e.g.:

```
BaseRepository
  ├─ UserRepository
  ├─ PostRepository
  └─ CommentRepository
```

I want to test my `BaseRepository` with a custom testing model, not with an actual application model (e.g. `User`, `Post`, etc), so i need to create this custom model with its migration and use them only during testing, but i'd prefer putting tose files into `tests` folder to keep the structure clean.

Is there a way to tell laravel to load other migrations other those in `app/database/migrations` only during testing?

#### Update #1: Why

I want to test my `BaseRepository` class in isolation, so i would not use any of my application model in the repository tests, since possible/future modifications/updates to those models may cause error in the repository tests, e.g. deprecation and subsequent deletion of that model from the codebase.

Thats why i would prefer to use a custom Model created just to be used in my repository tests.

Comment: Why you just don't create another database for testing, then create `.env.testing`, and configure that database
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/testing#environment

Comment: That's not what i'm asking for, i'm asking how to migrate a migration which file is not in the standard `app/database/migrations` folder, and doing it only during testing

Comment: I just wandering why you need to have other migration, in other folders? Can you explain me that part?

Comment: Updated the question to better explain why.

Comment: If your repository depends on models, then if you change something in model you need to update repository tests as well.
If you create another dummy model, then every time test with that dummy model you test will always succeed, then in the future if you change something in you real model, then run the tests, the tests will be ok, but real code will broke, because your repo in tests depends on dummy model that was not updated.

Comment: I just want to test te base repository with my dummy testing model since it will have generic and common operations implementations (e.g.: find, all, etc), other repositories extending the base one that implements more complex/specific operations will be tested with their correct models

Comment: Okay, very good!

Answer (score 0):

I found out I just can use the `Schema` facade in my test class in the `setUp`/`tearDown` methods to create/drop the table for my custom model before/after each test, i don't actually need a migration file.

Looking around i found this laravel package [lazychaser/laravel-nestedset](https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset): it cretes a new type of recursive relationship, and include a trait that it tests with a dummy model, creating its table just like said.